# Converting a content type into a Profile2 profile

Tags: nodes, users

I'm working on a site that's a user-contributed directory of local businesses. Each business that registers gets a user account.

I've thus far built the entire site using "Place" as a content type. However, in order to get users to contribute their listing as soon as they register (And to let the user easily edit that node), using Profile2 might make sense.

So, either one of two questions:

a. Is there any way of easily exporting a Drupal content type into something importable into Profile2?

b. Is there a way to get users to create a node just after or as they're signing up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question, create a view of the required information and using the [Views Data Export module](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) you can export it to a csv file.

Then you can import the information to users and profiles using the [User Import module](http://drupal.org/project/user_import).

To your second question, Rules will do it for them. Create a new rule executed on the event 'After Saving New Account' with the action of 'Create an Entity' and define the node you want created, using the new user as author.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to have users create a node on signup is to use [Logintoboggan](http://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan):

Create a new user Role called pre-auth and give it limited permissions. For example allow that role to create a particular content type. (To avoid spambots I would leave that content type set as unpublished.)

Then simply set Logintoboggan to allow login on registration, and redirect the user to node/add/your-content-type.

There is some self-explanatory configuration of the Non-authenticated role, the Welcome and Account activation email templates which are required; as Logintoboggan overrides the default account activation workflow.